# Best way to recover order for pandas Data-frame multivariate time series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a multivariate time-series, that I modeled in pandas Data-frame, to apply a recurrent neuronal network, the data frame needs to be sorted by time index. Then after the application of the model, prediction on test set, imply the same way of sorting. Hens, recovering order is a must.

Say data is like

```
+======================================================================================================================================================================================+
| index, target, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, feature7, feature8, feature9, feature10, feature11, feature12, feature13, feature14, feature15, feature16 |
+======================================================================================================================================================================================+
| 2014-01-01, 1, 12, 0.006750, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.602740, 117691.0, 0.06, 17259.0, 61491.0, 10.960000, 44620.0,                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-01-01, 1, 12, 0.256899, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.282192, 835.0, 0.06, 221.0, 344.0, 10.004412, 406.0,                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-01-01, 0, 12, 0.000500, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.282192, 49292.0, 0.04, 10853.0, 22945.0, 10.004412, 20132.0,                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Train and predict on ordered data-set

```
+======================================================================================================================================================================================+
| index, target, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, feature7, feature8, feature9, feature10, feature11, feature12, feature13, feature14, feature15, feature16 |
+======================================================================================================================================================================================+
| 2012-01-01, 0, 12, 0.000500, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.282192, 49292.0, 0.04, 10853.0, 22945.0, 10.004412, 20132.0,                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-01-01, 1, 12, 0.256899, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.282192, 835.0, 0.06, 221.0, 344.0, 10.004412, 406.0,                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01, 1, 12, 0.006750, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.602740, 117691.0, 0.06, 17259.0, 61491.0, 10.960000, 44620.0,                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then recover order of the predicted variable.

Comment: Pandas DataFrame's index is the best thing to keep the order of samples, it is not clear which problem do you have with it from your question.

Comment: ah, you have a point, I didn't mention, I set date as a time series index already.

Comment: Would the `df.reset_index()` fix the problem?

Comment: nice, I would accept this as an answer